# Only load certain artists on this page

Tags: php, functions, array

I have a wordpress page which loads all the artists in two columns... here is what I believe to be the relevant bit of code

```
<?php 
            global $paged;
            if ( is_front_page() ) {
                $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;   
            } else {
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
            }
            query_posts(array(
                'post_type'     => 'artists',
                'posts_per_page'    => $ppp_artists,
                'order'         => $order,
                'orderby'       => $orderby,
                'paged'         => $paged
            ));
            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="remix_items grid clearfix <?php echo $artists_col; ?>">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                <a class="item" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('type_cover'); ?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
```

I think I need to change the

```
'posts_per_page'    => $ppp_artists,
```

which is earlier defined where

```
global $post;
$artists_col = 'two_col';
$ppp_artists = ot_get_option('ppp_artists');
$orderby = ot_get_option('artists_orderby');
$order = ot_get_option('artists_order');
```

But what needs to be changed to make this only load 2 items? and not have pages buttons.

Comment: Don't use `query_posts()`, use `WP_Query()` instead. ([reason](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22728))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show only 2, put it as a value, like so:

```
'posts_per_page' => 2
```

For the newest posts, you need to change the sort using the order and orderby params:

```
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'ASC'
```

Details about orderby params here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Also, you should avoid the query_posts use. Except if you are using a part of your page only, I believe that's the case.

On Codex you can see on description about avoiding the query_posts use.

Check this video where a WP Core developer talks about query_posts and so on: http://wordpress.tv/2013/03/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query-wordpress-in-depth/

Comment: any chance of a helping hand with the orderby issue now>

Comment: Updated, check the orderby and order params

Answer (score 0):

so i removed the pagination by removing this from lower

```
<?php get_template_part('inc/pagination'); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h3><?php echo ot_get_option('no_artists'); ?></h3>
```

then changed

```
$ppp_artists = ot_get_option('ppp_artists');
```

to

```
$ppp_artists = 2;
```

which changed the number of posts to 2 however I need to load the first 2 posts not the last two so now I need to change it to load the oldest posts somehow :/

I changed the array at the top to

global $post;
    $artists_col = 'two_col';
    $ppp_artists = 2;
    $orderby = date;
    $order = ASC;

and I was away !